# Actionscript 3.0 Open windows explorer

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

So I have been trying to find an answer for this several hours this morning and last night. Thanks in advance. I have been trying to open a local folder by clicking a button and I am not getting the actionscript right. Because getURL is outdated I guess in AS3. But every other bit of my script is AS3 so I can't just use AS2.

Could anyone give me a solution to this?

Also, I already used the URLRequest method. Ended up opening "C:/..." in my web browser which as you can see, is not what I am trying to do.

Comment: An additional note, I am trying to make a stand-alone program. So this is not going online at all.

Comment: So, are you trying to open the windows explorer application on the client's computer? Or to get the current location of the .SWF file? I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Ok. So basically its for personal use. I have a lot of applications and folders that I access daily. Instead of navigating windows almost constantly. I am basically making it a couple clicks away. So what I am trying to do is find a AS3 code to open a folder when I click on a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make an Air App, then you will have access to NativeProcess (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html)

With NativeProcess class you can call windows explorer.

[ndm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392379/ndm) suggestion code's :

```
var f : File = new File("c:");
f.openWithDefaultApplication();
```

Comment: I'd suggest to check out [**`File.openWithDefaultApplication()`**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#openWithDefaultApplication()), this should open the explorer for directories.

Comment: I will give it a shot and get back to you on here. Thanks.

Comment: I did try that one out. I actually looked some things up. But still not getting it to work. But I've never used AIR before either, am I suppose to make a new project for that, or am I just throwing that code into the AS

Comment: Which IDE do you use ?

Comment: Just using Flash CS4.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS789ea67d3e73a8b21ec24feb12478b70aff-8000.html