# Open Windows Explorer in HTML pages

Tags: html, flash

I already know about the security and the browsers cant open the Windows Explorer directly.
But my question is:
Is there any kind of flash based object that do the trick?

Tks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071755/actionscript-3-0-open-windows-explorer.

Comment: I need this on my web site, online. A native program is not a option.